# casperjs multiple instances wont exit

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

i have a casperjs code as given below :

```
var links = [
    { url : "http://engadget.com/" , name : "eng" },
    {url : "http://shoryuken.com/2013/02/01/help-save-super-arcade/",name: "shir"},
    {url: "http://theverge.com/",name:"thever" }
];

var eng_done = false , shir_done=false, thever_done=false;
var casper = require('casper');
for(i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    var url = links[i].url;
    var name = links[i].name;
    var instance_i = casper.create();
    instance_i.start(url,function(){
        console.log("Loading: "+ name);
        name_done = true;

    });
    instance_i.run(function(){

        exit(i);
    });

}


function exit(idz){

        console.log("Now exiting instance no => "+idz);
        if(eng_done & shir_done & thever_done){
            idz.exit();
        }

}
```

As you can clearly see i am initiating 3 casperjs instances and exiting them at once, the thing is that its not properly exiting the instances as exit(i) always gets stucked to 3. I don't know what am i doing wrong in here... (Please , the URLS are just sample).

Comment: I didn't think you could have more than one casperjs running at a time.

Comment: actually i can have and its working perfectly fine except for exiting the threads after their completion... thats only problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i have finally found answer to my question, posting it here so it may help someone oneday someday out there :) i know code is a bit out standard but it works so i am ok with it :)

```
var view_width = 1024, view_height = 768;
var clip_width = 1366, clip_height = 768;
var settings = {
pageSettings : {
    loadImages : true,
    loadPlugins : false
}   ,
 timeout : 120000,
 // // Set the viewport size
 viewportSize: {width: view_width, height: view_height},
 // // Set the position and the size of the clipped image
 clipRect: { 
  top: 0, 
  left: (view_width - clip_width)/2, 
  width: clip_width, 
  height: clip_height 
 },verbose: true, logLevel: 'debug'
};
var links = [
    { url : "http://google.com" , name : "google" },
    {url : "http://bing.com",name: "bing"},
    {url: "http://facebook.com/",name:"facebook" }
];
var casper = require('casper');

currentLink = 0;
for (var i=0, item; item=links[i]; i++) {
  // item is "some", then "example", then "array"
  // i is the index of item in the array
  var name = item.name;
 var instance_i = casper.create({logLevel : "debug",
 verbose : true});
 captureTheImage(instance_i,item.url,item.name,i);

}

function captureTheImage(i,u,n,e){
    var google_done=false,
    bing_done=false,
    facebook_done=false;
    i.start(u,function(){
    // item.name_done = true;
    this.capture("c:/name_"+e+"_"+n+".jpg",undefined,{
            format: 'jpg',
        quality: 75
        });
     n_done = true; 
    });
    i.clear();
    i.run(function(){

    console.log("Links done : "+currentLink);
    currentLink++;
    if(currentLink == 3){
        this.exit();
    }

    });     

}
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Also, if you add more links, you can pass its value to captureTheImage and then where it says if(currentLink==) , define the length of current array there using links.length as in for loop. ;)

Best